# How do I change a value of a variable using an if else statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I've been on it for days but nothing is helping. The value of smallest does not change no matter what i do. it does not happen with the value of largest although it uses almost the same line of code.

```
smallest = None
largest = None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if num == "done":
        break
    try:
        x = int(num)
        if x < smallest:
            smallest = x
        elif x > largest:
            largest = x
    except:
        print"Invalid input"
        continue
print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Comment: You aren't dealing with the cases where `smallest` and/or `largest` are still `None`.

Comment: In Python 2, `None` is smaller than any other number. In Python 3, comparing an integer to `None` causes an error.

Comment: For the first time assign input values to both smallest and largest variable

Comment: Following up on @Barmar's comment: since it have been fixed in Python 3, there is absolute no reason for new code to rely on this quirky behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, (almost) never use a bare `except` statement. You will catch exceptions you can't or don't want to handle (like `SystemExit`). At the very least, use `except Exception`.

Second, your `except` block implies you only want to handle the `ValueError` that `int(num)` might raise. Catch that, and nothing else.

Third, the code that compares `x` to `smallest` and `largest` is independent of the `ValueError` handling, so move that out of the `try` block to after the `try/except` statement.

```
smallest = None
largest = None
num = "not done"    # Initialize num to avoid an explicit break
while num != "done":
    num = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    try:
        x = int(num)
    except:
        print "Invalid input"
        continue

    if smallest is None:
        smallest = x
    if largest is None:
        largest = x

    if x < smallest:
        smallest = x
    elif x > largest:
        largest = x

print "Maximum is", largest
print "Minimum is", smallest
```

Note that you can't fold the `None` checks into the `if/elif` statement, because if the user only enters one number, you need to make sure that *both* `smallest` and `largest` are set to that number. *After* the first number is entered, there is no case where a single number will update both `smallest` and `largest`, so `if/elif` is valid.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are, in both cases, comparing numbers to `None` in the first iteration. In Python 2, every number will come out as "greater" when compared to `None`, thus the code works for finding the maximum, but fails for finding the minimum.

BTW, in Python 3, the same would give you a `TypeError`.

To fix it, you can change your comparison to something like this, taking the `None` case into account:

```
if smallest is None or x < smallest:
```